# Should the "Law" tag should read "Legal"?

Tags: support, tags

I just suggested a description for the "Law" tag. However calling it "Law" sounds kind of funny.  Shouldn't it read "Legal"?  Maybe "Law" would be a synonym.

https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/law/info

Comment: Legal certainly seems more readable, but I question the validity of such a question since we try to stay away from these types of questions. Of the **[current, non-closed questions containing the world "legal"](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano+legal), I only see three where legal issues are the primary focus.

Comment: A related, but not exact tag could be "organizing" or "governance".  In other words - how to set up and run a community organization: bylaws, incorporation, etc.  Granted we obviously haven't seen that many questions for this topic yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've gone ahead and created a synonym and merged the tags. The new [legal](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) has the old [law](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) as a synonym.

- [Synonym list](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)